# Packing number lower bound for sparse vectors

Tags: packing-and-covering

Let $t \in (0, 1)$ and define $P_t(k)$ to be cardinality of the largest set of $t$-separated points (i.e., for any distinct pair of points, the Euclidean distance is strictly larger than $t > 0$) of the set
$$
S(k) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d : \|x\|_2 \leq 1, \|x\|_0 \leq k\}. 
$$
Above $\|x\|_0$ is the number of nonzero entries.

It is possible to show that for some constant $C > 0$, we have
$$
\log P_t(k) \leq C \, k \log \Big(\frac{e d}{k t}\Big), 
$$
for every $t \in (0, 1)$ and every positive integer $k \leq d$.

Can this inequality be reversed? Is it true that for some $c > 0$ we have
$$
\log P_t(k) \geq c\, k \log \Big(\frac{e d}{k t}\Big), 
$$
for all $t \in (0, 1)$ and every positive integer $k \leq d$?